# Component based routing using ui-router | AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router, angularjs-components

We had created a component named contact using angularjs@1.6 and angular-ui-router@1.0.0-rc.1.The problem lies on click of a button,nothing is displayed in the home page.It would be great if someone could help us to figure out the error.

### index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Component based routing</title>
    <!--Styles-->

    <!--Libs-->
    <script src="../libs/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="../libs/angular-ui-router.js"></script>

    <!--Components-->
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script src="contact/contact.js"></script>
    <script src="contact/contact.component.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <h1>Component based routing</h1>
    <div ng-app="app">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#/contact">Contact</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <h4>Test</h4>
        <ui-view></ui-view>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

### app.js

```
angular.module('app',[]);
```

### contact.js

```
angular
    .module('contactApp', ['ui-router']);
```

### contact.component.js

```
angular
    .module('contactApp')
    .config(['$stateProvider',function ($stateProvider) {
        $stateProvider.state('contact', {
                url: '/contact',
                component: 'contact'
            })
    }])
    .component('contact',{
        template: `<h1>Contact</h1>`
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

You app module, where component is registered, is `contactApp`. You need to change html to that app module:

```
<div ng-app="contactApp">
```

**EDIT**

If we assume that `app` is the main app module and there are other modules declared, then all the other have to be registered under that main app like this:

```
angular.module('app', ['contactApp']);
```

and then in html you use `app`, as you already do:

```
<div ng-app="app">
```

*You can also have multiple apps in the same html but it is not the recommented way

Comment: Assume we had multiple components with their respective modules;e.g home and contact.Do we have to register the app under a common module in the main page?